# GetModuleFileNameEx - ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwPID);

if (hProcess == NULL) return;

//
// Get process main module name.
//

wchar_t mainModName[MAX_PATH + 1];
size_t nameSize = GetModuleFileNameEx((HMODULE)hProcess, NULL, mainModName, MAX_PATH + 1);
```

`GetModuleFileNameEx` частенько возвращает 0. `GetLastError` говорит об ошибке 299 (`ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` - only part of a `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory` request was completed). Не могу понять в чём причина такого поведения, ведь программа запускается с правами администратора и даже предварительно получает привилегии отладчика (что влияет только на `OpenProcess` - даже для системных процессов удаётся получить `HANDLE`).

`GetModuleFileName` так же даёт ошибку (126 (`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`) - the specified module could not be found).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как уменьшить количество подобных ошибок?

Кстати, на Windows 10 это работает отлично, но это проблема появляется на Windows 7.

---

Раз уж речь зашла о WinAPI, спрошу ещё вот что:
Как я могу получить полное имя текущего пользователя?

`GetUserNameEx` неплохо справляется, но если задать первый параметр как `NameSamCompatible`, имя, если оно содержит пробел, будет неполным; а если указать `NameDisplay`, не будет поддерживаться русский язык (ну, по крайне мере, на Windows 7). По поводу русского могу сказать, что `GetUserNameExW` с параметром 
`NameDisplay` вернёт массив кракозябр. Как только я не пробовал выводить...

Например:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

TCHAR username[MAX_PATH + 1];
ULONG nNameSize = MAX_PATH + 1;
GetUserNameExW(NameDisplay, username, &nNameSize);
wprintf(L"%s\n", username);
```

Comment: Как минимум вот такой вызов - `wprintf(username);` - это просто издевательство... Надеюсь, это описка?

Comment: Ну `wcout` так же часто показывает всё правильно. Нет, это не описка. Почему это издевательство? `wprintf` принимает массив `const wchar_t` и печатает их на консоли.

Comment: Ну и как же по-вашему будем правильно это печатать?

Comment: @abyx Окей. Можете не отвечать на второй вопрос. Можете вообще считать, что его нет ;)

Comment: @Harry А, вы о `format`?.. Да, это описка)) Я думал вы имеете ввиду использование в этом примере `wprintf`.

Comment: В принципе да, но не дай бог в строке окажется процент? навсегда запомнил эту ошибочку - ну, как тот способ запомнить день рождения жены - один раз его забыть... :)

Comment: Это да. Но а если конкретно по делу? Будут предложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне пришла на помощь [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx). Работает исправно как на 7ке, так и на 10ке.
Как решить вопрос с именем пользователя я пока не знаю.

**UPD:**
Ну что понять можно было сразу, так это то, что `GetUserNameEx` просто не годится (при заявленных требованиях: полнота имени, поддержка русского). В документации на MSDN указано следующее:

> *NameFormat* [in] - The format of the name. This parameter is a value from the EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT enumeration type. It cannot be NameUnknown. **If the user account is not in a domain, only *NameSamCompatible* is supported.**